# Not rendering the view I specify

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is that when I want to render the new action after an error in the create action, it's render without the styles for that action.

This are the new action and create action from the same controller:

```
  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
      render layout: 'application'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{}
    end
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @role = Role.new
    @role.email = @user.email
    @role.tipo = "user"
    respond_to do |format|
      if @role.save
        #Not relevant
      else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: {:estado => "false"}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

One thing that I detected is that when I submit the form from the new action and it has and error, then the url is /users. Shouldn't it be /users/new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the URL is /users is standard in the rails framework. That is the POST #create route which includes the error_messages. 
The problem is this part in your 'new' action:

```
render layout: 'application'
```

A solution can be to add into your 'create' action:

```
render :new, :layout => 'application'
```

instead of just render :new.

So, use this instead:

format.html { render :new,  :layout => 'application' }

It will render your layouts/application.